# How would I convert a string data into Image

Tags: android, string, attributes

I cannot convert a string into attributeSet. I keep getting an error that my arguments don't match.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert a base64 string to an image?

Comment: No I mean how to convert a URL string into an image.

Comment: final LoaderImageView image = new LoaderImageView(this,getAnImageUrl() );    It says AttributeSet cannot be applied to java.string "getAnImageUrl" I don't understand the issue at all because it should work. It says the parameters don't match. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help you to convert your `base64` String into an image.

```
public void saveAsImage(String attachThumbnail) {

    byte[] previewImage = Base64.decode(attachThumbnail, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    final File file = new File("[dir]", "image_name" + ".jpg");
    save(file, previewImage);
}

/**
 * To save the content in a file.
 * 
 * @param file file to be store.
 * @param content actual data.
 */
public static void save(File file, byte[] content) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fos.write(content);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to load an image from URL, the best thing you can do is to use a good library. I'll suggest that use Glide library, because it's fast and stable. For that, add this line to your `build.gradle` file in `dependencies` section:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Then use this method for loading your desired `imageUrl` to your desired `ImageView`.

```
public void loadImageWithGlide(Context context, String imageUrl, ImageView holder) {
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .dontAnimate()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder);
}
```